# Android: a constant menu and changing activities

Tags: android, android-activity

I am working on a simple android app. 
I want to make a shared menu that is always visible (and always on top) and other activities that can be killed and can open other activities as well. 
I want to be able to click on objects (like text input fields) in my activities even if my menu has focus.

I just wonder what is a good way to implement the menu into my design[image]

*the activity screens can change while the menu stays visible at all times

**Update:**

- I would prefer a solution that will allow the menu items to hide (sliding to the left) and appear when you mouse over the left edge.
- I would benefit from actual code showing me how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use TabActivity or Fragment ???

Comment: I agree, using fragments would make sense in that case.

Answer (score 0):

To do what you're describing you will have to stay in just one Activity.  You can inflate different layouts into the right side while keeping your left side static.

so rather than making a bunch of different Activity classes, you would just create various layouts to populate the right side with and then inflate/destroy them as necessary.

In order to keep this from becoming a giant mess, you may want to extend View into separate classes that each inflate one layout... basically replicating the Activity model, except that rather than an Activity the thing you use is your own custom View which you build on the fly and throw into the right side panel (which would either be a child of a Relative or Table parent layout).

So...

```
TableLayout (full screen)
TableRow(full screen)
MenuView (left side)
   RelativeLayout (right side parent)
    -->> fill this with your custom View(s)
   /RelativeLayout
/Row
/Table
```

Something like this should work nicely.

Comment: Doesn't that mean that my views will not go through the activity life cycle and storing and restoring state will become a gigantic mess?

Comment: correct, if you can use fragments that would be preferable, but they're only available in the more recent versions of Android. I was only saying how you *could do this... not that you *should! :)